# How do update array values in Flutter cloud_firestore?

Tags: dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a document with an array field in it.

How can I update the array?

In firebase functions, with typescript, I did something like this:

```
admin.firestore()
    .collection('friendships')
    .doc(caller.data["uid"])
    .update({
        friends: admin.firestore.FieldValue
            .arrayUnion({
                          friendDisplayName: snapshot.data["friendDisplayName"],
                          friendUid: snapshot.ref
                       })
    })
```

I cannot find any alternative with Flutter.. how can I do?

Comment: this didn't work -  Firestore.instance.collection('friendships').document(caller.data["uid"]).updateData({
      'friends':{
        'friendDisplayName': snapshot.data["friendDisplayName"],
        'friendUid': snapshot.ref
      }
?

Answer (score 5):

Something like this

```
firestore.instance.
    .collection('friendships')
    .document(caller.data["uid"])
    .updateData({
  friends: FieldValue.arrayUnion({
    friendDisplayName: snapshot.data["friendDisplayName"],
    friendUid: snapshot.ref
  })
});
```

Comment: what does caller.data retrieve? I'm new to dart and i'm struggling to update array in my Firebase

Answer (score 4):

The solution I give you is when you use Transactions, but regardless of that, it works the same...

```
List<dynamic> list = List.from(documentSnapshot.data['uids']);
list.add(uid);
await documentTransaction.update(
  postRef,
  <String, dynamic>{
    'counter': documentSnapshot.data['counter'] + 1,
    'uids': list,
  },
);
```

Comment: The thing is that some times you don't have the ability to fetch the whole list and then add a new element. It would be nice if you could just add a new element to the existing array without fetching first