# Firestore nodes deleted on transaction

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

When I add to a document using below code I will successfully be able to keep adding additional objects to the array, as long as I stay on the same screen.

```
  void createRecord(dataMap) async {
    _user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
    var createTransaction = (Transaction tx) async {
      var ds = await tx.get(db
          .collection('users')
          .document(_user.uid)
          .collection("days")
          .document(DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(dataMap['day'])));
      await tx.set(ds.reference, dataMap);
    };
    Firestore.instance.runTransaction(createTransaction);
  }
```

[image]

After navigating off the screen then back all objects are deleted when trying to add new ones.
[image]

When I navigate back from a screen how can I add new objects to the collection with out deleting the old ones?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a new, unique item to an array, you can use the [`arrayUnion` operator](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array).

Something like:

```
await tx.update(ds.reference, {
                'breakfast': FieldValue.arrayUnion(dataMap['breakfast'][0])
      });
```

Also see:

- [how to add or remove item to the the existing array in firestore ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52150545/how-to-add-or-remove-item-to-the-the-existing-array-in-firestore)
- [flutter firestore, add new object in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53665155/flutter-firestore-add-new-object-in-array)
- [How do update array values in Flutter cloud_firestore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52728270/how-do-update-array-values-in-flutter-cloud-firestore)